# problems after reinstalling 2.8 in mac. weird acting, transparent panels, and crashes

Tags: interface, panel

Just reinstalled blender 2.8 cause my previous 2.8 had some issues with the parts of the bones in armature.

It´s the second try (yesterday it happened the same, but tried again today with newer update download), and similar results.

Now the panels look transparent, and the preference panel for example acts ver very weird with some diagonal lines in the middle.

Also wanted to ask if it is normal that when i reinstalled the updated version of blender after deleting the previous one it recognize already the previous shorcuts and preferences recorded in the deleted version.

Thanks in advance.

I´m noticing this issues running Blender blender-2.80.0-git20190604.d62a749fcf48-x86_64 
in a MacBookPro 9,2, Processor Intel Core i7, Processor Speed:2,9 GHz

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142072/bug-in-last-update-2-80